# Concluding a Group is a Subgroup

Tags: group-theory

I am working on a problem similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55485/if-h-and-gk-are-relatively-prime-then-h-leq-k). However, I am not understanding Geoff Robinson's answer.

For one, he says that "you don't really need normality, just that $HK=KH$ is a subgroup." As far as I understand, the only reason one can conclude $HK$ is a subgroup group is precisely because $K$ is normal.

Second: How does Geoff get that $|HK : K|$ divides $|G : K|$ and $|H : H \cap K|$ divides $|H|$?

Third, how does $|HK|/|K| = |H : H \cap K|$?

And why does $|HK : K| = |H : H \cap K|$, which Geoff seems to use in order to conclude that $|H : H \cap K|=1$?

I have spent a lot of time on this problem; I think my issue is that I have no intuition for the problem.

Comment: For one: nobody talked about the reason *why* $\;HK\;$ is a group. We know it is enough, **but not necessary**, that either one of them is normal. For two: $\;HK/K\le G/K\;$  so this follows from Lagrange's theorem, and $\;H/(H\cap K)\;$ is a homomorphic image of $\;H\;$ . For three and four: second (or third or something) isomorphism theorem.

Comment: @DonAntonio Ah, but what if we don't have the isomorphism theorems available?

Comment: Then I wouldn't be able to understand how someone could cope with such exercises, in particular since the isomorphism theorems are one the first things studied after the first definitions.

Comment: Hmm. That's disconcerting, especially since this exercise comes before the isomorphism theorems.

Comment: *Where* does it come "before"? A book, some notes, your course...?

Comment: It comes from the Dummit and Footes' Algebra book.

Comment: @Us Can you tell me precisely where in D&F's book? I can't locate it, and the isomorphisms theorems are in 3.3

Comment: @DonAntonio It is problem 18 in section 3.2.

Comment: I have both the second and third editions. In both problem 18 in section 3.2 is: let $\;G\;$ be a group and $\;H,N\le G\;,\;\;N\lhd G\;$ . Prove that if $\;|H|,\,[G:N]\;$  are realtively prime, then $\;H\le N\;$ . This is not related, as far as I can see, with the above question.

Comment: @DonAntonio Whoops...They seemed related. Would you mind helping me with this problem, perhaps giving some hints?

Comment: That $\;|HK:K|\,\mid\, |G:K|\;$ follows at once from Lagrange's theorem. That $\;|H:H\cap K|\,\mid\,|H|\;$ follows from the fact, that if $\;\phi:G\to G'\;$ is a groups homomorphism, then $\;|\phi(G)|\,\mid\,|G|\;$ ...but I can do this with the first isomorphism theorem. Without it, or without something equivalent to it,  just can't. Perhaps someone else.