# If $N\lhd G$, $|N|$ finite, $H < G$, $[G: H]$ finite, and $[G: H]$ and $|N|$ are relatively prime, then $N < H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The following is Exercise I.5.20. from Hungerford's *Algebra* (GTM 73).

> If $N\lhd G$, $|N|$ finite, $H < G$, $[G: H]$ finite, and $[G: H]$ and $|N|$ are relatively prime, then $N < H$.

I only found the problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55485/if-h-and-gk-are-relatively-prime-then-h-leq-k?rq=1), where $G$ is assumed to be finite. But when $G$ is infinite I don't know what to do. The second isomorphism theorem does not apply here. Any hints will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We claim that $[N: H\cap N] =1$, but it follows from $[N:H\cap N]$ is a divisor of $|N|$ and $[G:H]$.

The assertion $[N: H\cap N]\mid [G:H]$ may need a proof, and it is a consequence of $[NH : H] = [N: H\cap N]$.

Comment: Thanks! I just mistakenly thought that this equality does not hold for infinite groups... Silly of me. :)

Comment: @Hanul Jeon : Well, shouldn't $[NH : H ] = [H : H \cap N]$?

Comment: @crskhr Consider the map $n(H\cap N)\mapsto nH$. It is well-defined, and we have $n(H\cap N)=n'(H\cap N)$ iff $nH=n'H$. Hence the map is one-to-one. Since every element of $NH$ is of the form $nh$, the map is also onto.

Comment: @HanulJeon Thank you :)